# How to set a custom property for conditional import in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, pubspec

Dart allows to use the standard library names for conditional import/export, like this:

```
export 'src/hw_none.dart' // Stub implementation
    if (dart.library.io) 'src/hw_io.dart' // dart:io implementation
    if (dart.library.html) 'src/hw_html.dart'; // dart:html implementation
```

Is it possible to define a custom property/condition? For example, pass it when compiling.

I have a project that I would like to split into two variants: Flutter variant and pure Dart variant. The choice of the variant depends at compile time, and the necessary implements of abstract classes  defines at compile time.

Answer (score 1):

Custom properties where an experimental feature in Dart 1. With Dart 2 there is no longer any support for user defined custom conditions in compile time.

[Here](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/34262#issuecomment-416129832) is the discussion referencing your question.

All you can do is, switch between implementations on run time:

```
abstract class SomeFactory {  
  String get message;
  
  factory SomeFactory() {
    if(Platform.environment['SOME_VAR'] != null)
      return new _SomeImplementation();
    return new _SomeOtherImplementation();
  }  
}

class _SomeImplementation implements SomeFactory {  
  @override
  String get message => 'SomeImplementation';  
}

class _SomeOtherImplementation implements SomeFactory {  
  @override
  String get message => "OtherImplementation";  
}
```

Check [this blog entry](https://medium.com/@dvargahali/dart-2-conditional-imports-update-16147a776aa8) for more details.

Comment: Runtime checks are not suitable because I need to build a project with different dependencies. For example, in one version I need Flutter, and in the other I don't.

Comment: I see but this is currently not possible for custom defined properties. What you can do is move the common code base into a plugin and split the rest into two projects.